# How to change the color of bullets in a list

Tags: lists, color

How can I change the color of bullets in a book?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,29,119}

\begin{document}

\begin{dinglist}{110}
  \item{Sample text}

  \begin{dinglist}{228}
    \item{Sample text}

   \begin{dinglist}{227}
     \item{Sample text}

   \end{dinglist}
  \end{dinglist}
\end{dinglist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can define custom item commands:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,29,119}

\newcommand{\bsquare}{\item[\color{myblue}\ding{110}]} 
\newcommand{\barrow}{\item[\color{myblue}\ding{228}]}
\newcommand{\bwarrow}{\item[\color{myblue}\ding{227}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{dinglist}{110}
  \bsquare{Sample text}

  \begin{dinglist}{228}
    \barrow{Sample text}

   \begin{dinglist}{227}
     \bwarrow{Sample text}

   \end{dinglist}
  \end{dinglist}
\end{dinglist}

\end{document}
```

or as per Christoph B comment (same preamble):

```
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \bsquare Sample text

  \begin{itemize}
    \barrow Sample text

   \begin{itemize}
     \bwarrow Sample text

   \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Normal `itemize` environments should suffice, making your solution independent of the `pifont` package.

Answer (score 19):

The following MWE provides `\itemcolor{<colour>}` that allows you to set the colour of the list item as you wish:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pifont,xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,29,119}
\newcommand{\itemcolor}[1]{% Update list item colour
  \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\color{#1}\hfil ##1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{dinglist}{110}
  \itemcolor{myblue}
  \item Sample text
  \begin{dinglist}{228}
    \itemcolor{green!70}
    \item Sample text
    \itemcolor{red!50}
    \item Sample text
    \begin{dinglist}{227}
      \item Sample text
   \end{dinglist}
  \end{dinglist}
\end{dinglist}

\end{document}
```

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides a list-wise hook into the items via the `label` key-value:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,pifont,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,pifont,xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,29,119}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label={\color{myblue}\Pifont{pzd}{\char110}}]
  \item Sample text
  \begin{itemize}[label={\color{green}\Pifont{pzd}{\char228}}]
    \item Sample text
    \item Sample text
    \begin{itemize}[label={\color{red!50}\Pifont{pzd}{\char227}}]
      \item Sample text
   \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

As usual, you don't have to define these lists at the document level. It can be done within the preamble, separating structure from content. See the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) (section **5 Global settings**, p 9) and the use of `\setlist[<list type + level>]{<format>}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack into `pifont` and redeclare one of its commands, for example `\Pisymbol`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,29,119}

\newcommand{\myPisymbolformatcommand}{}

\newcommand{\hackintoPisymbol}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\myPisymbolformatcommand}{#1}
}

\renewcommand{\Pisymbol}[2]{{\Pifont{#1}\myPisymbolformatcommand\char#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{dinglist}{110}
  \item{Sample text}

  \begin{dinglist}{228}\hackintoPisymbol{\color{myblue}}
    \item{Sample text}

   \begin{dinglist}{227}
     \item{Sample text}

   \end{dinglist}
  \end{dinglist}
\end{dinglist}

\end{document}
```