# Change color of enumerated list to indicate correct answer

Tags: beamer, color, lists

I have a question about changing the font color in enumerated lists. I have seen several questions with good answers about how to change bullet colors but I haven't seen one that works for my case.

I use beamer slides during lectures that have multiple choice questions on them. I show the slide. Students answer. Then I show the answer. I want to indicate the correct answer by changing the color of the incorrect options. My problem is that I cannot figure out a way to do this within the itemize or enumerate environments. At least not in a way that will change the color of the answer option (A, B, C, D etc.) at the same time as the text. I have developed a workaround to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}
\definecolor{grey}{RGB}{169,169,169}
\newcommand{\fd}[1]{{\color{grey}{#1}}}  % fd just means "fade". There is no special meaning.

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    The wealthiest economies are those where people are:
    \vskip10pt

    \only<1>{
        A. generalists (do many things pretty well).     \\ \vskip5pt
        B. specialists (do one thing really well).
        }
    \only<2>{
    \fd{A. generalists.}                                 \\ \vskip5pt
        B. specialists.
        }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a solution. I combined the redundant text in one enumeration and added two new commands `\falseanswer` and `correctanswer`.

How to change Item Color I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110101/how-to-change-the-color-of-bullets-in-a-list).

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}
\definecolor{grey}{RGB}{169,169,169}
\newcommand{\fd}[1]{{\color{grey}{#1}}}  % fd just means "fade". There is no special meaning.

\newcommand{\itemcolor}[1]{% Update list item colour
    \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\color{#1}\hfil ##1}
}
\newcommand{\falseanswer}[1]{
    \only<1>{\itemcolor{blue}\item #1}
    \only<2>{\itemcolor{grey}\item \fd{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\correctanswer}[1]{
    \itemcolor{blue}\item #1
}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}
        The wealthiest economies are those where people are:
        \vskip 10pt
        \begin{enumerate}
            \falseanswer{generalists\only<1>{ (do many things pretty well)}.}
            \correctanswer{specialists\only<1>{ (do one thing really well)}.}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. This looks like a perfect solution. Much better than what I was doing. Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 1):

### [image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}
        The wealthiest economies are those where people are:

        \begin{enumerate}
          \item<+> generalists\only<.>{ (do many things pretty well)}.
          \item<.-+> specialists\only<.(-1)>{ (do one thing really well)}.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well this is interesting. It seems so simple I almost don't believe it. I didn't see this in the beamer manual. Clearly I need to look again.

Comment: I've been looking at the manual about this solution. Not sure it's going to work for me. I'm having issues when I have more than two options. Even more though, I would rather not have to change the action options all the time.

The first method I showed, flawed though it may be, lets me just use **cor** and **fal** for correct and false. It might just be unique to my workflow but it seems to be more efficient in my case.

I'm still looking into some other options. `\alt<2>{}{}` or `\item<1-| alert@2>` look promising, but I still need to get the list color and letters right.