Color an item in an enumerated list (continued; not a duplicate)
I'd like to color some (but not all) item numbers in an enumerate environment (package enumitem). I followed
an approach mentioned here, but it fails if only the item number is to be colored:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor, hyperref, thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}\mbox{}
  \begin{enumerate}
    {\color{red}\item\label{item1} Item 1\dots\ appears in red but I only want to color the number.}
    {\color{red}\item\label{item2}} Item 2\dots the item number is pushed down (under 3).
  \item\label{item3} Item 3\dots\ a non-colored item.
    {\color{red}\item\label{item4}\!\!} Item 4\dots\ the item number now appears in the right place, but is indented with the space manually removed (which is a hack but shows what I try to achieve).
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}
Referring to \ref{item1}, \ref{item2}, \ref{item3}, \ref{item4} works (and must work in a viable solution).
\end{document}

As you can see, colored item 2 appears under item 3. How can this be avoided? Using a \strut or \mbox will avoid this but introduces unwanted horizontal (item indentation) space (which I removed manually in the last item via \!\! to show what I try to achieve -- again, only for selected items, otherwise one could work with label= of course).

Thanks, Mico, I now updated the question to clarify it.

Hi, any arbitrary combination should be colored or not, it depends on the context, so for example items 2, 3 and 5 out of a list of 7 items should be colored. If you know any solution to the introduced horizontal space, I'd already be happy, I wouldn't want to define new environments or use additional packages to make it more convoluted than necessary.

You can define a command \itemcolor like in  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110104/.

You should add the color inside the item label.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor, hyperref, thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{lemma}
\newcommand\myitemcolor{}
\newcommand\setitemcolor[1]{\def\myitemcolor{\color{#1}}}
\newcommand\unsetitemcolor{\def\myitemcolor{}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
  \begin{enumerate}[format=\myitemcolor]
  \setitemcolor{red}
    \item\label{item1} Item 1\dots\ appears in red but I only want to color the number.
    
    \item\label{item2} Item 2\dots the item number is pushed down (under 3).
  \unsetitemcolor
    \item\label{item3} Item 3\dots\ a non-colored item.
    
  \setitemcolor{green}    
    \item\label{item4} Item 4\dots\ 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}
Referring to \ref{item1}, \ref{item2}, \ref{item3}, \ref{item4} works (and must work in a viable solution).
\end{document}


